# Pass value from UIApp or Google Spreadsheet to gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, uiapplication

I'm using Google Apps for Education. Since my Principal does not allow me enable Shared contact, and the paid version of Shared Contacts for Gmail is not satisfied my needs.

I am thinking the way to integrate address book to users' gmail in following options:
Option1 :Is it possible writing Google script UIApps for users to select recipients
by checkbox(es) and click "selected", then the values (ie. chosen email
address(es)) will pass to To: / Cc: / Bcc: fields on gmail?

Since I find some page show Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); to get email address, does it have any commands, like set, to paste email address to active user?

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45852/google-script-for-pulling-gmail-addresses-into-a-spreadsheet

Option2: If it is possible, can I insert this UIApss on Google Spreadsheets, because I would like only few Google Groups of users to browse it, not anyone within our campus

Option3: Or can I directly use Google Spreadsheets, allow users selecting particular recipients and pass their selected email address to our campus's gmail (To: / Cc: / Bcc:) fields?

Otherwise, I may only create a Google Spreadsheets for them to copy the email address and paste on Gmail recipient fields. This is my last solution, but my principal does not quite accept this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the details, but I'm pretty sure that both options 1 and 2 are possible. In terms of option 1, it is definitely possible, and you should definitely give the UiService a good look. It would definitely help you in creating that user interface, just as you described above. I don't know for sure if you can embed that set of objects in a spreadsheet, but you probably could, using the onOpen() function to start the app when the spreadsheet is opened up. If that is for sure possible, then I would enjoy that as well (I'm working on a Gmail-oriented app myself currently, and that's where I want to build my UI on, because of easy long term data storage).